# Automate logging in to website using c#

Tags: c#, cookies, https, webclient, fiddler

I want to login to a website every 5 hours to automate some tasks. I am having trouble login in because the website uses https.

I want to login to https://www.dealercentral.net . If I use fiddler meanwhile logging in this is the request and response that I captured where the username and password are being sent (note I modified the username and password for security reason otherwise you will be able to login to my account lol):

Request captured by fidler:

```
POST https://www.dealercentral.net/_layouts/15/dealercentral/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2f HTTP/1.1
Host: www.dealercentral.net
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 439
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://www.dealercentral.net
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://www.dealercentral.net/_layouts/15/dealercentral/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2F
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=52lhv2bm45z5xx0kylecwzco; WSS_FullScreenMode=false

__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPBSpWU0tleTo3NDM1NGQ1ZS1iYjBkLTQ2ODktYTU4Mi0xMDgzNTljY2ZjY2Zk7GQ77o%2B8NvANoTxtWC0wkDqyACylBde9E2t7U%2BOXkCY%3D&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAATYiJ%2B%2Fud3KAWRxdbdx6iTIIRPZSl6UajYNUBbXmOsn5sIjdzfOst76JdbTNlFHv6h6%2Ff%2BTYHJ2sj56xvBVZVdouyYzuVuGagw4zrs8XpBj6eWYF7phR6ki3BEBwJxSZQ0%3D&signInControl%24UserName=USERNAME_I_MODIFIED_THIS_ON_PURPOSE&signInControl%24password=_PASSWORD_THAT_I_ENTERED_&signInControl%24login=Sign+In
```

Response capured by fiddler

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private, no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: FedAuth=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; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
SPRequestGuid: e34f259d-4b05-104d-f0d8-cf3b39ea9ef5
request-id: e34f259d-4b05-104d-f0d8-cf3b39ea9ef5
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
SPRequestDuration: 201
SPIisLatency: 0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4551
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 21:57:39 GMT
Content-Length: 158

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

If I where to have `__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPBSpWU0tleTo3ND.... etc` and all the cookies I will be able to sign in. Once logged in I know what request I have to made in order to parse the data that I need. Its just I am having trouble logging in. **I am also doing this to learn.** I know there are a lot of web automators out there.

---

**I know how to sign in with fiddlers help (If I copy the headers and posted data that was captured using fiddler sign in works!):**

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
c.Headers.Add("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=52lhv2bm45z5xx0kylecwzco; WSS_FullScreenMode=false");
// add other headers captured by fiddler
var html = c.UploadString("https://www.dealercentral.net", "__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPBSpWU0tleTo3NDM1NGQ1ZS1iYjBkLTQ2ODktYTU4Mi0xMDgzNTljY2ZjY2Zk7GQ77o%2B8NvANoTxtWC0wkDqyACylBde9E2t7U%2BOXkCY%3D&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAATYiJ%2B%2Fud3KAWRxdbdx6iTIIRPZSl6UajYNUBbXmOsn5sIjdzfOst76JdbTNlFHv6h6%2Ff%2BTYHJ2sj56xvBVZVdouyYzuVuGagw4zrs8XpBj6eWYF7phR6ki3BEBwJxSZQ0%3D&signInControl%24UserName=USERNAME_I_MODIFIED_THIS_ON_PURPOSE&signInControl%24password=_PASSWORD_THAT_I_ENTERED_&signInControl%24login=Sign+In");
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is ok and the login is successful.

Your login url is:

```
https://www.dealercentral.net/_layouts/15/dealercentral/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F&Source=%2f
```

So, when login completes, the server response is:

```
Object moved to <a href="/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2F">here</a>.
```

which means the server is redirecting to that url because your login is ok.

Comment: My question is how do I login? I was able to login because I stole the parameters from fiddler. If fiddler did not exist how do I do it :/ . thanks for the help

Comment: A tip: If you really want to learn this, you should learn HTTP protocol first. In this case, maybe you should send two HTTP request. One "GET request" to get viewstate, lastfocus, etc and all the cookies. And a "POST request" to send the previous values plus the user credentials.